# Can't get my Kubuntu VM full screen on Windows 7 host

Tags: virtualbox, display

Cannot take advantage of my 1280x1024 display to have seamless or fullscreen Kubuntu VM. I tried installing guest additions by doing

1. click **Devices > install guest additions**
2. In konsole run `sudo /media/<username>/VBOX.../VBoxLinuxAddition.run`

and rebooting, but still stuck at 1024x768.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that gcc is required

solution:

- install `build-essential`
- run `VBoxLinuxAddition.run`
- reboot